# How to continue on a single Redux Actions for particular time

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, settimeout

I have been developing react native application, and its combined with redux. And i have successfully implemented a coupon system. What i want to achieve is, i want to continue an certain action for at-least 3 seconds.

Here is the action:

```
export const onAcceptingCoupon = (value) => {
 return(dispatch) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({ type: APPLY_BUTTON_LOADING, payload: true });
        }, 50000);
    dispatch({ type: DISCOUNTED_PRICE, payload: value });
    dispatch({ type: APPLY_BUTTON_LOADING, payload: false });
  }
};
```

So, i have been using react native elements button. By which it has a loading option, which will show a loader in front of button Text. So the problem is when i press on the button above mentioned action is called.

As the data i needed is already fetched, i just want to loader to be active for 3 seconds min. So that, user can understand that something is happening.

So, i tried to use setTimeout but nothing happened. It just moved to next dispatch.

How to manually stop dispatch to move to next dispatch, until a certain seconds ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your order is a little messed up. You want to start the loading first, then after a period of time stop the loader. Perhaps changing the order to this will allow you to have more success.

```
export const onAcceptingCoupon = (value) => {
 return(dispatch) => {
    // show the loader
    dispatch({ type: APPLY_BUTTON_LOADING, payload: true });

    // put the code that should execute after 50000 inside the setTimeout
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({ type: DISCOUNTED_PRICE, payload: value });
        dispatch({ type: APPLY_BUTTON_LOADING, payload: false });
        }, 50000);
    }
};
```

`setTimeout` isn't blocking, code that is written after it will execute normally. It just causes the code in the timeout to execute after the time period has passed.